# How to get the content of a class within a variable

Tags: typescript

I have a Manager who hold Scene which are `PIXI.Container` and it's can access the content of a scene via the variable this._scene
so example I could go and do `this._scene.update();`

Although I am unsure how to make the system being able to detect dynamically the content of the scene (which scene can be of multiple names but they are **all** the children of `Scene_Base` who share common method.)

So my first approach was this:

```
interface  ISceneConstructor {
    new(): Scene.Base;
}
```

then assign it to `private static _scene: ISceneConstructor = null;`

Although when I do:

```
this._scene.methodName();
```

it's say it's can find the method name on `ISceneConstructor` when it's supposed to refers to the class Scene_Base or any scene who are passed to the `_sceneVariable`.
It's **not** directly called by new by referenced from another variables who is:

```
this._nextScene = new sceneClass(); <-- which is a type of ISceneConstructor
SceneManager.changeScene = function() {
    if (this.isSceneChanging() && !this.isCurrentSceneBusy()) {
        if (this._scene) {
            this._scene.terminate();
            this._scene.detachReservation();
            this._previousClass = this._scene.constructor;
        }
        this._scene = this._nextScene; // <-- where you see the assignation.
        if (this._scene) {
            this._scene.attachReservation();
            this._scene.create();
            this._nextScene = null;
            this._sceneStarted = false;
            this.onSceneCreate();
        }
        if (this._exiting) {
            this.terminate();
        }
    }
};
```

So how I could possibly get the content of the actual scene without having to destroy the library? (because yes I am using a existing library I am converting to Typescript!